# How to sort in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Hello here is my current code:

```
$sqlpack = "Select * from package_in_plan where plan_id='$package_id' order by plan_id";
$planres = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlpack);

$plan = array();
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($planres)){
    $plan[] = $row1['package_id'];
}

$plan_1 = implode(',', $plan);
for ($x = 0; $x < count($plan); $x++) {
    $sql_service = "Select * from service_in_package where package_id='".$plan[$x]."'";
    $chid = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_service);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($chid)){
        $ch_id = $row['service_id'];

        $sql = "Select * from itv where status='1' and id='$ch_id' order by number asc";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
            $nr = $row['id'];
            $namn = $row['name'];
            $chnr = $row['number'];
            echo $nr;
            echo $namn;
            echo $chnr;
        }
     }
}
```

What i need is the output to be sorted by number($chnr), right now my code is not sorting because it's receiving specific id from previous select ($ch_id).
How can i let the output of $results to be sorted "order by number".
Number is INT in itv table.

Comment: Do you know about SQL joins?

Comment: I just answered this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720440/php-how-to-run-a-while-loop-in-another-while-loop/38722548#38722548 explaining why you shouldn't query in a nested loop. Yours is even worse because your nesting is three deep!

Comment: @e4c5: Welcome to the wonderful world of answering the same question thousands of times a day from different users who can't be bothered to undertake the slightest research before posting...

Comment: @eggyal but these users are pretty good at creating topics in documentation :-)

Comment: @e4c5: I've literally stopped clicking on "Documentation"—it makes me nauseous.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of subqueries which results in a single query that can be sorted.

```
$sql = "Select * from itv where status='1' and id IN 
(Select service_id from service_in_package where package_id IN 
(Select package_id from package_in_plan where plan_id='$package_id' order by plan_id)) 
order by number asc";
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    $nr = $row['id'];
    $namn = $row['name'];
    $chnr = $row['number'];
    echo $nr;
    echo $namn;
    echo $chnr;
}
```

Comment: 504 Gateway Time-out, any idea?